How does Android parse resources.arsc for certain apps? AAPT and AAPT2 are giving different results
I am trying to put an android app APK to my analysis tool. Specifically Microsoft "Company Portal" (version 5.0.6295.0 as of this writing, you can download it and pull from device via adb) Play Store Link.
This tool is supposed to extract the string resources from the resources.arsc file but it seems to not parse the ResStringPool headers correctly and gets a StringCount and StyleCount too large, causing the read to go beyond the boundary. Every other app I've tested has been fine. And I've confirmed that the app installs fine on several devices.
I've also noticed that there are different results using different versions of Google's  AAPT tool.
For reference, here's comparison of output for 2 apps:
$ aapt dump strings CompanyPortal.apk | head
# Outputs: String pool of 41756 unique UTF-8 non-sorted strings, 41756 entries and 41743 styles using 3531384 bytes: (incorrect)
$ aapt2 dump strings CompanyPortal.apk | head
# Outputs: String pool of 41801 unique UTF-8 non-sorted strings, 41801 entries and 529 styles using 3203980 bytes: (correct)

$ aapt dump strings NormalApp.apk | head
# Outputs: String pool of 12217 unique UTF-8 non-sorted strings, 12217 entries and 13 styles using 589388 bytes:
$ aapt2 dump strings NormalApp.apk | head
# Outputs: String pool of 12217 unique UTF-8 non-sorted strings, 12217 entries and 13 styles using 589388 bytes:

So it seems clear that my tool works the same as AAPT v1 and I need to somehow incorporate the change that AAPT2 has to get an accurate count. When I extract the resources.arsc from the 2 apps I see
$ od -x CompanyPortalresources.arsc | head
0000000 0002 000c a0b8 0054 0001 0000 0001 001c
0000020 (e278 0035) (a31c 0000) (a30f 0000) 0100 0000 # (3531384, 41756, 41743)
0000040 18c8 0005 3f78 0033 0000 0000 0003 0000
0000060 009a 0000 0133 0000 01cc 0000 025b 0000

$ od -x NormalAppresources.arsc | head
0000000 0002 000c e5a8 000e 0001 0000 0001 001c
0000020 (fe4c 0008) (2fb9 0000) (000d 0000) 0100 0000 # (589388,12217,13)
0000040 bf34 0000 fd74 0008 0000 0000 0036 0000
0000060 005c 0000 0074 0000 0096 0000 00ba 0000

with a hex lookup we can see where the incorrect values are coming from, so I first assumed it was just different encoding, but looking at all the representations in this web hex tool I still can't see where aapt2 is pulling the correct values from. Specifically I don't see 0211 anywhere in the hex dump of the file.

3531384 => 0x0035e278, 41756 => 0x0000A31C, 41743 => 0x0000A30F
3203980 => 0x0030e38c, 41801 => 0x0000a349,  529 => 0x00000211
589388 => 0x0008fe4c, 12217 => 0x00002fb9,   13 => 0x0000000d

Below are other links I've used for reference, but as far as I can tell, they all seem to suggest reading Int32 at the same spot to get the counts, but I'm not good at reading C/C++ so maybe I'm missing something. Any tips/help would be much appreciated, thanks for your time.

General description of resources.arsc
Apk parsing tool jadx (written in Java)
AOSP platform tools
AOSP aaptcompiler
Android studio AAPT2

UPDATE: 2024-08-02
aapt2/cmd/Dump.cpp shows that it gets the table from APK and calls 3 argument ResStringPool constructor
int DumpStringsCommand::Dump(LoadedApk* apk) {
  ResourceTable* table = apk->GetResourceTable();
  //...
  android::StringPool::FlattenUtf8(&buffer, table->string_pool, GetDiagnostics());
  auto data = buffer.to_string();
  android::ResStringPool pool(data.data(), data.size(), false);
  Debug::DumpResStringPool(&pool, GetPrinter());

aapt2/Debug.cpp Shows printed value should be the same as pool->size()
void Debug::DumpResStringPool(const android::ResStringPool* pool, text::Printer* printer) {
  SortedVector<const void*> uniqueStrings;
  const size_t N = pool->size();
  for (size_t i=0; i<N; i++) {
    size_t len;
    if (pool->isUTF8()) {
      uniqueStrings.add(UnpackOptionalString(pool->string8At(i), &len));
    } else {
      uniqueStrings.add(UnpackOptionalString(pool->stringAt(i), &len));
    }
  }
  printer->Print(StringPrintf("String pool of %zd unique %s %s strings, %zd entries and %zd styles using %zd bytes:\n", uniqueStrings.size(), ... 
}

ResourceTypes.cpp & ResourceTypes.h seem to show it coming from mHeader->stringCount with constructor which also just calling data.convert()
size_t ResStringPool::size() const
{
    return (mError == NO_ERROR) ? mHeader->stringCount : 0;
}

status_t ResStringPool::ResStringPool(incfs::map_ptr<void> data, size_t size, bool copyData)
{
  //...
  const auto chunk_header = data.convert<ResChunk_header>();
  const bool notDeviceEndian = htods(0xf0) != 0xf0; // htods=host to device short?
  const auto header = data.convert<ResStringPool_header>();
  mHeader = header.verified();
  if (notDeviceEndian) {
    h->stringCount = dtohl(mHeader->stringCount); // dtohl = device to host long?
  }

utils/ByteOrder.h seems to have dtohl and htods do nothing, I think it's just leftover from old versions (see 4.2.2_r1 example)
UPDATE: 2024-08-09
I ended up setting up the whole AOSP build system and made a custom aapt2 exe with extra logging. I found that BinaryResourceParser::ParseTable

first handles RES_STRING_POOL_TYPE which gives value_pool_.size()=41756 value_pool_.styleCount()=41743
then handles RES_TABLE_PACKAGE_TYPE which gives
string_pool.strings().size() 41272 string_pool.styles().size() 529, (add to 41801)
This indeed seems to come from a while loop in BinaryResourceParser::ParsePackage which runs until ResChunkPullParser::IsGoodEvent() is faluse, so it is not reliant on the values in the original header.


In addition to the number of entries there is often a size/length field. If the parser reaches the end of the defined section it stops parsing new entries. Therefore you may not find the correct value at all as it is implicitly defined by the section size.
